# How To Dynamically Generate CSV File And Attach Into Email

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0

Please Help me.

My problem is, I am generate(create) csv file using printwriter object to write some data into csv file and at a time attach this csv file into email.
When my code is execute csv file is generate successfully and i received email with attachment csv file but csv content is not readable format.

So please help me how can i do?

```
public void SendMail(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    String filename = "Testcsv.csv";
    resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

    PrintWriter fw = ((ServletResponse) resp).getWriter(); 
    fw.append("#");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("Product code");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("Product");
    fw.append('\n');
    fw.append("1");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("12345");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("testing");
    fw.append('\n');
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();

    String csvFile = fw.toString();

    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   //String host = "localhost";
    String from = "emailaddress";
    String toAddress = "emailaddress";
    // Get system properties
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    message.setSubject("JavaMail Attachment");
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText("Here's the file");
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(csvFile.getBytes(),"text/csv")));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName("testcsv.csv");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);

    try {
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");
    } catch (SendFailedException sfe) {
        System.out.println(sfe);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using PrintWriter , use StringBuilder or just string. I had tried this and it works.

Hopefully it will be useful.

```
    //PrintWriter fw = ((ServletResponse) response).getWriter();
    StringBuilder fw = new StringBuilder();
    fw.append("#");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("Product code");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("Product");
    fw.append('\n');
    fw.append("1");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("1");
    fw.append(',');
    fw.append("ABHISHEKKKKKK");
    fw.append('\n');
    //fw.flush();
    //fw.close();

    String csvFile = fw.toString();
```